# Связанные свойства товаров в каталоге продукции

Tags: алгоритм, php, mysql

Всем привет.

Есть каталог продукции, содержащий товарные группы, product_group:

```
id name
1  Автомобили
2  Мотоциклы
```

Для каждой группы созданы свойства, например, для Автомобилей, product_properties:

```
id name    parent gid
1  Брэнд     0     1
2  BMW       1     1
3  Audi      1     1
4  Модель    0     1
5  X5        4     1
6  X5        4     1
7  A1        4     1
8  А2        4     1
9  Мотор     0     1
10 xDrive35i 9     1
11 xDrive50i 9     1
12 1.2 TFSI  9     1
13 1.4 TFSI  9     1
```

Т.е. свойства связаны друг с другом:

```
БМВ / X6 / xDrive35i
AUDI / A1 / 1.2 FTSI
```

И не может быть, например,

```
БМВ / А1 / xDrive35i
AUDI / A1 / xDrive35i
```

Как правильно их связать с товарными позициями, учитывя что при открытии категории товаров мы должны увидеть их атрибуты в следующем виде:
Как их лучше ассоциировать с товарными позициями учитывая что придется делать следующий вывод группы каталога Автомобили:

```
BMW
  Х5
  Х6
Audi
  A1
  A2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше было в первой таблице сделать дерево с флагом  is_category (Автомобили[1] - БМВ[1] - X5[0]), во второй свойства вида [element_id, name, value]

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, в моём случае очень  простое и удобное решение, большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

В своем примере вы спутали название атрибута и значение атрибута, поэтому поместили их в 1 колонку. атрибуты нужно вынести в отдельную таблицу (бренд, модель, мотор, итд). а по теме:

```
/* группы продуктов*/
table product_groups: group_id, group_name, ...

/* свойства продукта (а еще лучше названия хранить отдельно т.к. бывают разные одинаковые названия)*/
table product_properties: product_id, product_name, ...

/* связки свойств по группам и продуктам. где все поля часть первичного ключа */
table product_properties_def: product_group_id, product_id, related_product_id

бинд конкретных брендов:
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 1, 2); -- привязка БМВ к брендам
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 1, 2); -- привязка Ауди к брендам

бинд конкретных моделей автомобилей:
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 4, 5);
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 4, 6);

привязка моторов:
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 9, 10);
insert into product_properties_def values (1, 9, 11);
```

если вы планируете деревообразный обход продуктов:
1) сначала выбирается бренд  (вершина дерева)
2) выбирается модель (модель привязана к бренду)
3) выбираются другие аттрибуты (привязаны к конкретной модели)

то у вас на каждом шагу получается простой запрос вида:

```
select * from product_properties 
where product_id in 
(select product_id from products where name = ? /* brand name */)
```

если у вас есть необходимость создавать сложные фильтра для данных тогда вам нужна еще 1 таблица `product_properties_def_flat` аналогичная таблице `product_properties_def`. разница в том что последняя будет хранить развернутые данные:

```
связывание атрибутов без прямой зависимости ():
insert into product_properties_def_flat values (1, 1, 5);
insert into product_properties_def_flat values (1, 1, 6);
insert into product_properties_def_flat values (1, 1, 10);
insert into product_properties_def_flat values (1, 1, 11);
```

таблица `product_properties_def_flat` должна обновлятся триггерами повешенными на `product_properties_def`и содержать все допустимые комбинации атрибутов, ее размер будет значительно больше и она будет содержать в себе все данные из `product_properties_def`.

Comment: Интеренсное решение, буду иметь его ввиду, спасибо :)